# How to disable the autoloading of a specific module in Linux

Tags: linux, module, autostart

I compiled my Linux kernel according to the *Linux Device Driver* Chapter 4: Debugging Techniques. After I loaded my first hello world module and then checked the output by `dmesg`, however, all I can see is `evbug: .......`.

I know I can turn off `evbug`'s output by execute `sudo rmmod evbug`. But, obviously, it is inconvenient to execute this command after each reboot.

How could I disable this module's autoloading? I just want to load it manually when I need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to blacklist the module. For debian systems see https://wiki.debian.org/KernelModuleBlacklisting. For redhat systems see https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/rescuemode_drivers-blacklisting.html